# jquery t prevent second click

Tags: jquery

Stumbled upon one annoying problem - initially people were able on double click to add a product to shopping cart TWICE. I used one() function that seemed to help but I've just discovered it added a bug. Please have a look at the code:

```
$('#add_now').one('click touchstart', function(){   


    if(option != null) // "if an item is selected" check
    {
// ajax request to add to cart
    }
    else{

         $('#report').hide().html('<span style="color: #af0000;">Please choose quantity!</span>').fadeIn('500').delay(2000).fadeOut(500); 
    } 

    return false;

    });
```

so now, it certanly works only once so if anything is selected  - error message is shown but after that people cannot add anything even if they choose a product. It's because of the **one()** function that prevents script from firing more than once. I could reload the page after the "Please choose quantity" report but it is a lame solution. Hmm.....

so , basically - if I'll change **one()** back to **click()**  - it will work pretty much liek it should save the problem with double add on double click.

Comment: Instead of `.one()` use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handler in the `if` branch

Comment: you need to track the cart contents outside of this and cross-reference what they have checked vs. what is already in the cart.  PS - adding items to cart multiple times is generally accepted as a way of buying more than one of that item

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem ... and  more like a logic problem. Need to update existing item in cart if there is a match

Comment: So the more generalized question you're asking is: how to prevent a double click on a button doing something twice.

Comment: This question lacks the actual specification for how it should work.  Are you trying to prevent the same item from being added to the cart more than once, no matter when the second click comes?  If so, then you need to expose your cart data.  Or are you trying to just prevent rapid back-to-back clicks from being processed as multiple clicks?  If so, then you can "debounce" the click either with a utility function or a third party jQuery plug-in.

Comment: I "think" you application works like this:

1) Use selects a number of items
2) Range of items in selection is added once x is pressed
3) Re-clicking an item adds it directly

Can you confirm this is the case, or offer a differing specification?

Comment: @Andreas - add your comment as an answer please. going to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an timeout:

```
var clickDisable;
$("button").click(function () {
    if(!clickDisable) {
        clickDisable = setTimeout(function(){
            clickDisable = false;
        }, 500);
        //Do something
    }
});
```

This prevents the button from doing something for 500ms after clicking it.

Comment: instead of true and false just set the clickDisable to the setTimeout so it's null or has the timeout pending.  Still gotta clear it if the user is clicking a million times I'm guessing.

Comment: Good idea :D.  @Deryck

Comment: Are you serious? If the OP wants a pink turtle in a svg animation then that's what he wants, it's not for us to devide what the op wants. Reported for the downvote.

Comment: reported who for downvote...can check my vote logs and see it wasn't me. Not to mention votes are discretionary ... anyone is entitled to vote any way they wish

Comment: Can't check vote logs, not a high enough score for that :P And voting is something that's not fully discretionary, abuse of voting is not allowed :)

Comment: opinions can differ on validity of a specific vote ... but that isn't abuse

Comment: Voting an answer is about the answer not about the op his code/question in general.